# Search Issue in SP2007

Tags: search, application-pool, registry

We had some disk space issue on our search server and after which search is not working and displaying the error "The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service". 1 server is used as Index and query server.

In Central Administration --> Search administration page, I see the below error

[image]

I also see the below errors in Event log of search server every minute:

**Error 1:**

[image]

**Error 2:**

[image]

**Error 3:**

[image]

**Registry missing in Prod:**

I could see a registry entry related to search missing in Prod:

**UAT Registry:**

[image]

**Prod Registry:**

[image]

**Below are my troubleshooting steps:**

1. Restarted OSearch service.
2. Ran Product Configuration Wizard.
3. Cleared file cache on all SP servers.
4. Recreated SSP using a new DB and got the same error even in new SSP.
5. Re-attached SSP Content DB.
6. Restarted all search related services and restarted even search server.
7. Reset the index.

**Observations:**

1. I see that App pool of SSP getting stopped whenever any search related pages are hit in Central Admin.Even if i start it, it gets stopped as soon as a search page is hit in Central admin.
2. I created a new app pool and associated the application to the new app pool but still face the same issue

Can someone help me on how to proceed with the troubleshooting and help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue following the below steps/actions:

Basically there were 2 issues, one is the registry entry was missing/broken, next IIS application.host config file was corrupted because of which IIS app pools identity were not getting authenticated.

**Fixes**

**1. Registry Issue:**

Fixed the registry issues by deleting the registry entry from Database and then created registry entry again by restarting search services.

Executed the below query on "SSP" database on SQL server to delete the registry entry from Database:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.MSSConfiguration WHERE Name = N'RegistryBlob'
```

Once the registry was deleted in database, I re-provisioned/re-started search services using Central administration. This created the registry entries related to search.

> **Reference:** https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/703ec525-ae5f-4dd6-8fd6-d8b92da534ee/sp2007-search-is-borked-cannot-provision-service?forum=sharepointsearchlegacy

**2. IIS App Pool Identity Issue:**

- Copy the applicationhost.config file from one of the servers in the
  farm where IIS is working fine and paste it in the issue server. The
  file will be available in the below path:

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

- Export the WAS and Configuration Key from working server using the
  below script:

> ```
>    cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
>      aspnet_regiis -px "iisConfigurationKey" "D:\iisConfigurationKey.xml" -pri 
>      aspnet_regiis -px "iisWasKey" "D:\iisWasKey.xml" –pri
> ```

- Copy the exported WAS and Configuration key xml files from D:/ of
  working server and paste it on D:/ of problematic server.
- Import the WAS and Configuration Key on problematic server using the
  below script:

> ```
>    cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
>      aspnet_regiis -pi "iisConfigurationKey" "D:\iisConfigurationKey.xml" -exp 
>      aspnet_regiis -pi "iisWasKey" "D:\iisWasKey.xml" -exp
> ```

- Restart the below services on problematic server:

> ```
> • Windows SharePoint admin 
>   • Windows SharePoint timer
>   • Windows SharePoint search
>   • Office Search server
> ```

- IIS Reset /no force

> **Reference:** http://webdebug.net/2014/02/iis7-error-bad-data-0x80090005/